# How to render a type based on another type in typescript?

Tags: typescript-typings, react-typescript

```js
export enum TemplateType {
  Email = "Email",
  Sms = "Sms",
}
export type SmsBinding = {
  date: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
};

export type EmailBinding = {
  recipients: string[];
  templateBindings: SmsBinding;
};

export interface CrmMessagesDataType {
  id: string;
  subject: string;
  bindings: SmsBinding | EmailBinding;
  createdAt: string;
  isArchived: boolean;
  isDraft: boolean;
  isRead: boolean;
  status: CrmMessageStatus;
  type: TemplateType;
}
```

How do I make "bindings" in interface "CrmMessagesDataType" of type SmsBinding or EmailBinding based on if "type" is of "Email" or "Sms" in a destructuring?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Template arguments**

```js
export interface CrmMessagesDataType<T extends SmsBinding | EmailBinding> {
  id: string;
  subject: string;
  bindings: T;
  createdAt: string;
  isArchived: boolean;
  isDraft: boolean;
  isRead: boolean;
  type: TemplateType;
}

const data1: CrmMessagesDataType<SmsBinding> = {
  id: '',
  subject: '',
  bindings: { date: '', first_name: '', last_name: '' },
  createdAt: undefined,
  isArchived: true,
  isDraft: true,
  isRead: true,
  type: TemplateType.Sms,
};
const data2: CrmMessagesDataType<EmailBinding> = {
  id: '',
  subject: '',
  bindings: { recipients: [''], templateBindings: { date: '', first_name: '', last_name: '' } },
  createdAt: undefined,
  isArchived: true,
  isDraft: true,
  isRead: true,
  type: TemplateType.Email,
};

const { bindings } = data1; // bindings is of type SmsBinding
const { bindings } = data2; // bindings is of type EmailBinding
```

**2. Type Casting**

```js
const data: CrmMessagesDataType = {
  id: '',
  subject: '',
  bindings: { date: '', first_name: '', last_name: '' },
  createdAt: undefined,
  isArchived: true,
  isDraft: true,
  isRead: true,
  type: TemplateType.Sms
};

const { bindings } = data;
if (data.type === TemplateType.Email) {
  (<EmailBinding>bindings).templateBindings;
}
if (data.type === TemplateType.Sms) {
  (<SmsBinding>bindings).first_name;
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that the data that carries this interface is coming from an api. I then want to access the values inside binding based on the TemplateType.

Comment: Ah I see, I added if-statements based on TemplateType in my second example for type-casting.